# Translating Magento categories in 1.9.0.1 -> Missing checkbox in store view for translation

Tags: category, localisation

I am setting up a second language store. We use the same root category. What I do is the following: I open the store view of the second language and want to start translating.

The weirdest thing: *the checkbox in store view* to "Use Default Value" (and thus override defaults) is completely missing. Now I would not know how to translate ...

**question:** is there a setting? or soemthing I need to do to enable the translation per store view in categories again?

Or has anyone seen this before?

many thanks

---

Examples

**What I would expect to see**

[image: What I would expect to see]

**What we are currently seeing - notice the missing checkbox**

[image: What we are currently seeing - notice the missing checkbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form elements should be displayed using this template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml` (unless you changed that, but I doubt you did).
There is an `if` statement for displaying the checkbox.

```
<?php if ($this->canDisplayUseDefault()): ?>
<td class="value use-default">
    <input <?php if($_element->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> type="checkbox" name="use_default[]" id="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId() ?>_default"<?php if ($this->usedDefault()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode.parentNode)" value="<?php echo $this->getAttributeCode() ?>"/>
    <label for="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId() ?>_default" class="normal"><?php echo $this->__('Use Default Value') ?></label>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So my guess is that `$this->canDisplayUseDefault()` returns false for some reason.
The method is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element`

```
public function canDisplayUseDefault()
{
    if ($attribute = $this->getAttribute()) {
        if (!$attribute->isScopeGlobal()
            && $this->getDataObject()
            && $this->getDataObject()->getId()
            && $this->getDataObject()->getStoreId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Start debugging here to see what's wrong.

Solution (provided by OP based on the indications from the answer): Using the above you can discover a Module or Extension that is causing problems. In this case disabling "https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids" solved the issue.

Comment: super! I will investigate and post the resolution

Comment: @snh_nl. Yeah..I forgot to mention, this is not a full solution. I wasn't able to reproduce it. And my answer did not fit in a comment.

Comment: The problem was actually related to another extension (BubbleShop Dynamic Category Products) and not to Enhanced Admin Grids, as explained here : https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/issues/115#issuecomment-61480180

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, please follow the below mentioned procedure and you'll be good to go with your translation!

- Go to `System` -> `Configuration` -> `Genera`l -> `Locale Options`
- Change `configuration scope` to your New Store[image]
- Then select the language you want to assign at `Locale Options` -> `Locale`
- Now, Clear cache and check in front-end

Comment: euh. I know how to change my default language. The question is why the option to override default values in store view (checkbox) under categories is missing